# Nvidia driver error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, nvidia

I tried to install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 to work with Cuda following mostly official guides. But some of the libraries that I was going to use needed another version of Cuda, so I tried to reinstall it manually. I wasn't making notes while doing it, so I don't know what exactly went wrong.

Now except the problem with drivers, I can't even update or reboot the system properly:

1. In normal mode, the system does not boot (or it boots, but for a very long time; I waited for an hour, and turned it off). I'm loading now in insecure mode, but not everything is loaded this way. For example, the second screen does not connect, the brightness is not adjusted, and it does not go into sleep mode.
2. If I try to update via terminal or Software Updater, I get the error.

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

nvidia-cuda-toolkit: Depends: nvidia-profiler (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but 9.1.85-3ubuntu1 is installed
                     Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not installed
                     Depends: opencl-dev but it is a virtual package
                     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0) but 1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
```

After commands
**sudo apt update**
**sudo apt full-upgrade**
the error is:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I try **sudo  apt --fix-broken install** I get

```
Unpacking nvidia-cuda-dev (9.1.85-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas.h', which is also in package libcublas-dev 10.2.2.89-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried such commands as
**sudo apt-get clean**
**sudo apt install nvidia-settings**
**sudo apt autoremove**
**sudo apt autoclean**
**sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall**

but got the same error.

I tried to remove files that are pointed in errors:
**sudo mv nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb /home/sergey/Trash/**
**sudo mv cublas.h /home/sergey/Trash/**

But it gave no effect.

I also can't remove nvidia modules:

**sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'**

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-dkms-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-driver-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-utils-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-modprobe (>= 440.33.01)
                Depends: nvidia-settings (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

My system is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
[nvidia-smi output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS3gJ.png)
[cards information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrhNO.png)

I saw other people's issues like mine, but their solutions don't work for me. I will appreciate any help on this.

UPD: I noticed that CUDA is actually working. For instance, in Pytorch.

Comment: For the ...remove --purge nvidia*, try quoting the (non-expanding) "nvidia*", try usnig bash instead of fish which handles unexpanded wildcards differently, and anyway, try "*nvidia*" to get rid of all the nvidia packages.

Comment: @ubfan1, thank you for an advise. I tried to correct the syntax and to use bash. Now I get another error.

Comment: This is my gist for CUDA 10.0 installation on my PC. Hope it can help.
https://gist.github.com/zendobk/b79e2f2bbbb74e8d7fad060f22f8162e

Comment: I had similar problems until I realized that cuda version is very important; I finally succeeded using `cuda-10-1` (not -10-2), and `libcudnn7*[7.6.5.2]`; `nvidia-driver-440` works fine with them